# Flask-SQLAlchemy doesn't create table with using MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, flask, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to use MySQL with Flask-SQLAlchemy.
When I try to create a table it's not getting created.

Down is my code and error raised:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
import pymysql

pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb()
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'mysql+pymysql://root:''@localhost/alchemy'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False

db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True)

    def __init__(self, username, email):
        self.username = username
        self.email = email
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Ivan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\pymysql\connections.py", line 581, in connect
    sock = socket.create_connection(
  File "C:\Users\Ivan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\socket.py", line 808, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "C:\Users\Ivan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\socket.py", line 796, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] Nie można nawiązać połączenia, ponieważ komputer docelowy aktywnie go odmawia

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Ivan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 2285, in _wrap_pool_connect
    return fn()
  File "C:\Users\Ivan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 363, in connect
    return _ConnectionFairy._checkout(self)
  File "C:\Users\Ivan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 773, in _checkout
    fairy = _ConnectionRecord.checkout(pool)
  File "C:\Users\Ivan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 492, in checkout
    rec = pool._do_get()
  File "C:\Users\Ivan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\sqlalchemy\pool\impl.py", line 139, in _do_get
    self._dec_overflow()
  File "C:\Users\Ivan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\sqlalchemy\util\langhelpers.py", line 68, in __exit__
    compat.raise_(
  File "C:\Users\Ivan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py", line 178, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "C:\Users\Ivan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\sqlalchemy\pool\impl.py", line 136, in _do_get
    return self._create_connection()
  File "C:\Users\Ivan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 308, in _create_connection
    return _ConnectionRecord(self)
  File "C:\Users\Ivan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 437, in __init__
    self.__connect(first_connect_check=True)
  File "C:\Users\Ivan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 657, in __connect
    pool.logger.debug("Error on connect(): %s", e)
  File "C:\Users\Ivan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\sqlalchemy\util\langhelpers.py", line 68, in __exit__
    compat.raise_(
  File "C:\Users\Ivan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py", line 178, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "C:\Users\Ivan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 652, in __connect
    connection = pool._invoke_creator(self)
  File "C:\Users\Ivan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\sqlalchemy\engine\strategies.py", line 114, in connect
    return dialect.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
  File "C:\Users\Ivan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py", line 488, in connect
    return self.dbapi.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
  File "C:\Users\Ivan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\pymysql\__init__.py", line 94, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Ivan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\pymysql\connections.py", line 325, in __init__
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Users\Ivan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\pymysql\connections.py", line 630, in connect
    raise exc
pymysql.err.OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' ([WinError 10061] Nie można nawiązać połączenia, ponieważ komputer docelowy aktywnie go odmawia)")

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Ivan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\flask_sqlalchemy\__init__.py", line 1033, in create_all
    self._execute_for_all_tables(app, bind, 'create_all')
  File "C:\Users\Ivan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\flask_sqlalchemy\__init__.py", line 1025, in _execute_for_all_tables
    op(bind=self.get_engine(app, bind), **extra)
  File "C:\Users\Ivan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\sqlalchemy\sql\schema.py", line 4320, in create_all
    bind._run_visitor(
  File "C:\Users\Ivan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 2057, in _run_visitor
    with self._optional_conn_ctx_manager(connection) as conn:
  File "C:\Users\Ivan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\contextlib.py", line 113, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "C:\Users\Ivan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 2049, in _optional_conn_ctx_manager
    with self._contextual_connect() as conn:
  File "C:\Users\Ivan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 2251, in _contextual_connect
    self._wrap_pool_connect(self.pool.connect, None),
  File "C:\Users\Ivan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 2288, in _wrap_pool_connect
    Connection._handle_dbapi_exception_noconnection(
  File "C:\Users\Ivan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1554, in _handle_dbapi_exception_noconnection
    util.raise_(
  File "C:\Users\Ivan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py", line 178, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "C:\Users\Ivan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 2285, in _wrap_pool_connect
    return fn()
  File "C:\Users\Ivan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 363, in connect
    return _ConnectionFairy._checkout(self)
  File "C:\Users\Ivan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 773, in _checkout
    fairy = _ConnectionRecord.checkout(pool)
  File "C:\Users\Ivan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 492, in checkout
    rec = pool._do_get()
  File "C:\Users\Ivan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\sqlalchemy\pool\impl.py", line 139, in _do_get
    self._dec_overflow()
  File "C:\Users\Ivan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\sqlalchemy\util\langhelpers.py", line 68, in __exit__
    compat.raise_(
  File "C:\Users\Ivan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py", line 178, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "C:\Users\Ivan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\sqlalchemy\pool\impl.py", line 136, in _do_get
    return self._create_connection()
  File "C:\Users\Ivan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 308, in _create_connection
    return _ConnectionRecord(self)
  File "C:\Users\Ivan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 437, in __init__
    self.__connect(first_connect_check=True)
  File "C:\Users\Ivan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 657, in __connect
    pool.logger.debug("Error on connect(): %s", e)
  File "C:\Users\Ivan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\sqlalchemy\util\langhelpers.py", line 68, in __exit__
    compat.raise_(
  File "C:\Users\Ivan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py", line 178, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "C:\Users\Ivan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 652, in __connect
    connection = pool._invoke_creator(self)
  File "C:\Users\Ivan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\sqlalchemy\engine\strategies.py", line 114, in connect
    return dialect.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
  File "C:\Users\Ivan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py", line 488, in connect
    return self.dbapi.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
  File "C:\Users\Ivan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\pymysql\__init__.py", line 94, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Ivan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\pymysql\connections.py", line 325, in __init__
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Users\Ivan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\pymysql\connections.py", line 630, in connect
    raise exc
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (pymysql.err.OperationalError) (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' ([WinError 10061] Nie można nawiązać połączenia, ponieważ komputer docelowy aktywnie go odmawia)")
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)
```

Comment: If the root password is the empty string, the connection string would be `'mysql+pymysql://root:@localhost/alchemy'`

Comment: Try, as you said, but it steel raise this long errors

Comment: 1. Is the server running?  2.  Is the firewall allowing connections on port 3306?

Comment: Yes:(Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/)
2. Is the firewall allowing connections on port 3306? How can I check it?